# Retrieving and Comparing Dates using JQuery And PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery's datepicker in wordpress/PHP and I am using this code to show dates:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("option","dateFormat",'yy-mm-dd');
    });
</script>


 Date<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="20" maxlength="15"  style="width: 80px;" readonly="readonly"/>
```

It successfully displays my date.

Also, I have a table (wp_redeem_vouchers) in the database that has specific voucher  redemption dates saved in it:

```
  id       wp_deal_id            redeem_date
  1      Amazon6767           2012-03-21
  2      Ebay87nm             2013-06-12
  3      M&Svouc              2013-01-01
  4      ASDA                 2011-09-08
```

**Question:**

1. How can I retrieve "redeem_date" and compare with the datepicker's textbox date (upon selection) with the date already saved in the database?
2. Is there anyway I could disable past date so that user can't choose the past date from date picker? i.e The user on 14/03/2013 can't choose 22/02/2013 from datepicker.

Comment: I know you can limit the earliest date to select from with datepicker.  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: @deed02392.But what about the first part of the question?

Answer (score 2):

For your i)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

           $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "some.php",
                   data: { date: dateText },
                   onSuccess: function(e){
                    alert("success");
                  }
                });
        });
```

Then in the `some.php` file you do your compare with mysql and you return a success or failure getting the alert(success).

Then I would start with

```
      $date = $_POST['date']; 
      die($date);
```

In the some.php just to see if it is passed correctly.

Comment: @idipous.Not working.it stopped displaying my datepicker.Not validating against the some.php!my some.php code:                                                      $sql="select redeem_date from wp_redeem_vouchers where redeem_date=".$_POST['datepicker']." AND wp_deal_id=".$_SESSION['id'];
    $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
    
      $redeem_date=$row['meta_value'];
        
    }
    if ($redeem_date==$_POST['datepicker'])
    {
        return true;  
    }else{
        return false;
    }

Comment: @idipous.could u edit your answer to explain it in detail?Thanks

Comment: @BiL see my edit. I am sorry for the errors in javascript. Was in a hurry. Maybe there are a few more. If the datepicker is not working the php has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @idipous.Thanks.But i am not getting response back using the above code.

Comment: @idipous.See above comment.How would i get my response back on the same page as the php bits are working fine!

Comment: So do you get the onsucess alert? What exactly do you mean by php working fine? You don't have the die() anymore right? You could return a "true" from the php script if you get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can pass your datepicker date string (adjust format to `$("#datepicker").datepicker("option","dateFormat",'yyyy-mm-dd');`) to following JavaScript function which creates a `Date` object:

```
function createDate(s) {
    var bits = s.split('-');
    var d = new Date(bits[0], bits[1] - 1, bits[2]);
    return d;
}
```

Then you have to retrieve the date value from your database. 
I do not know if there is a wordpress limitation but you can trigger a Ajax-Request which reads out the database value and give you as a response the date string as a JavaScript variable.

This variable can also be passed to the `createDate(date)` function. With these two date objects you can call easily compare the date with the time in milliseconds -> `getTime()` function of date object.

Regards